# Flutter web PWA install prompt from within the app

Tags: flutter, installation, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web, homescreen

I'm working on a Flutter Web PWA app and having trouble with triggering the Add To Home Screen prompt from within the flutter app.  I understand it can be triggered using Javascript with the code below, but how do I do this from my Flutter dart file?

```
buttonInstall.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Hide the app provided install promotion
  hideMyInstallPromotion();
  // Show the install prompt
  deferredPrompt.prompt();
  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
  deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
    if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
      console.log('User accepted the install prompt');
    } else {
      console.log('User dismissed the install prompt');
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: A PWA install prompt will show when viewing the PWA website in the browser using HTTPS and it is a valid PWA. Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: Thanks Mathias.  That part is all good.  I was hoping to trigger the "install to desktop" after user clicks on a button.

Comment: You can create your own button (on your WEBSITE) to install a PWA. The only way to install a PWA is from a website page ONLY IF the browser determines your PWA is valid.

Comment: @HarjotPanag were you able to solve it ? I'm also looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Flutter web can only prompt PWA installs from the browser. The issue with displaying PWA install prompt is it breaks the compatibility/design with Android/iOS builds as the feature is web-specific.

A different approach that you can take here is by displaying "PWA install" reminders when the app is run on web. Otherwise, it's best to file this as a [feature request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I created the [pwa_install](https://pub.dev/packages/pwa_install) package specifically for this purpose.

## 1. Update index.html

```
<!-- Capture PWA install prompt event -->
<script>
    let deferredPrompt;

    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
      deferredPrompt = e;
    });

    function promptInstall(){
       deferredPrompt.prompt();
    }

    // Listen for app install event
    window.addEventListener('appinstalled', () => {
      deferredPrompt = null;
      appInstalled();
    });

    // Track how PWA was launched (either from browser or as PWA)
    function getLaunchMode() {
      const isStandalone = window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches;
      if(deferredPrompt) hasPrompt();
      if (document.referrer.startsWith('android-app://')) {
        appLaunchedAsTWA();
      } else if (navigator.standalone || isStandalone) {
        appLaunchedAsPWA();
      } else {
        window.appLaunchedInBrowser();
      }
    }
</script>
```

## 2. Call PWAInstall().setup()

You can call this method in main.dart before calling runApp()

```
Future<void> main() async {

  // Add this
  PWAInstall().setup(installCallback: () {
    debugPrint('APP INSTALLED!');
  });

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: App()));
}
```

## 3. Check if the Install Prompt is enabled

Before calling the `promptInstall_()` method, you can check if the Install Prompt is available using `PWAInstall().installPromptEnabled`.

`installPromptEnabled` will be true if:

The app was launched in a browser (It doesn't make sense to prompt a PWA install if the app is already running as a PWA)
The `beforeinstallprompt` event was captured.
`promptInstall_()` won't do anything if installPromptEnabled is false so you should check this flag before attempting to call the prompt.

## 4. Call PWAInstall().promptInstall_()

Finally, call PWAInstall().promptInstall_() to show the install prompt.

Note that this will not work on Safari since Safari does not implement the beforeinstallprompt method this package relies on.

Comment: Is this still working, because for me the install prompt is not showing on any of my devices(several Android devices)